# Pandas smarter conditional merge for two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

Here I tried to find the shortest possible example code for a conditional merge of two dataframes. There I try to merge exact rows based on a condition. Currently I have to itterate both dataframes for that.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([
    ['a', 'Test1', 2995],
    ['b', 'Test2', 3995],
    ['c', 'Test3', 5000]],
    columns=['ID', 'Name', 'Value'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([
    ['1', 1, 2],
    ['2', 3, 4],
    ['3', 99, 100]],
    columns=['ID', 'Start', 'Context'])

df_test = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID', 'Name', 'Value','Start'])
i = 0
for index, row1 in df1.iterrows():
    for index, row2 in df2.iterrows():
        if row1['Value'] + 25 > row2['Start'] * 1000 and row1['Value']< row2['Start'] * 1000:
            df_test.loc[i] = row1
            df_test.loc[i]['Start'] = row2['Start']
        i += 1
```

And it works so the dft_test is

```
     ID Name  Value Start
  0  a  Test1 2995  3
```

is there a smarter way doing that ?

Comment: `pd.merge_asof` or an intervalindex can help here

Answer (score 3):

Use [`janitor`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor)'s [`conditional_join`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) with intermediate columns:

```
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor

out = (
 df1.assign(Value_25=df1['Value'].add(25))
    .conditional_join(
        df2.assign(Value_1000=df2['Start'].mul(1000)),
        ('Value_25', 'Value_1000', '>'),
        ('Value', 'Value_1000', '<'),
        df_columns=list(df1),
        right_columns=['Start']   
    )
)
```

Output:

```
  ID   Name  Value  Start
0  a  Test1   2995      3
```

Comment: Thanks for that, actually we try to replace pandassql as it seems to be not maintained anymore. janitor looks promissing but is Version 0.26 as the only released version. Would there be a pandas/python native solution ?